# SQL windowed function/rownum/order by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to see how often a customer has requested Re-Activation of their Internet account.

The problem is, we capture a limited set of data to group on. So my data set is below.

I am trying to Count from the first time a Re-Activation request was created until the First time it was COMPLETED, once it has been completed finish the count of days it took for the request to complete and count the number of NON COMPLETIONS and SENT statuses which occurred between that time.

Below is an image of the sample data as well as the sql for the table. Hope somebody can provide a little help. (using SQL server 2005 compatibility)

[image: IMAGE OF PROBLEM AND WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE]

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
Identifier varchar(20)NOT NULL
,CreatedDate DATETIME NOT NULL
,CompletedDate DATETIME NOT NULL
,SN_Type varchar(20) NOT NULL
,SN_Status varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
;

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160729','20160805','Re-Activattion','SENT');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160810','20160810','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160812','20160812','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160811','20160811','Re-Activattion','COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160811','20160813','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('61030203647','20160427','20160427','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20160425','20160425','Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20160422','20160422','Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20170210','20170210','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203688','20170409','20170210','Re-Activattion', 'SENT');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203699','20170409','20170210','De-Activattion', 'COMP');
```

Comment: Good job on providing a DDL and sample data that we can use! To make it quicker for you in the future, you can comma separate your insert instead of typing `INSERT INTO #temp` each time. `INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (...,...,...,...,...),(...,...,...,...,...)`.

Comment: where are you getting the minimum created dates for 610302023647? I don't see that date in the created date at all, much less for that ID.

Comment: How do you order your data to get the *HAVE*  result?

Comment: @scsimon Does the comma syntax for values work on an INSERT in SQL 2005? I think that's only SQL 2008+. However you can use INSERT...SELECT...UNION ALL syntax in 2005.

Comment: @Danielle and just to clarify, your question says 2005-compatible but you have tags for both 2005 and 2008. Is it 2005? If so, can you change your tags, please?

Comment: I missed your version, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this covers your requirement or not,

```
select identifier,count(1) as cnt,sum(case when sn_status = 'N-CO' then 1 else 0 end) as non_com_cnt ,sum(case when sn_status = 'SENT' then 1 else 0 end) as
 sent_cnt, datediff(dd,min(case when sn_status = 'SENT' then createddate end),max(case when sn_status = 'COMP' then completeddate end)) as diff,min(case when sn_status = 'SENT' then createddate end) as start_date,max(case when sn_status = 'COMP' then completeddate end)  from #temp where sn_type = 'Re-Activattion' group by identifier;
```